# Add-in project must be .NET 3.5 rest of the codebase is .NET 4.0 how to solve?

Tags: c#, add-in, autodesk

I wrote an add-in for [Inventor 2012](http://usa.autodesk.com/autodesk-inventor/), the add-in must be .NET 3.5 it seems. I have not found an update that enables .NET 4 yet.
The rest of my codebase is .NET 4.0 and hence I cannot reference my other projects from my add-in code. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Does the rest of your codebase rely on .NET 4?  If not and you can compile (the pertitant codebase) to .NET 3.5, you could use those portions and still reference those in your other .NET 4 projects.

Comment: Honestly I dont know how much of the codebase that relies on .NET 4 features, it is the entire teams code.
By compile to you mean change target framework for other projects?

Comment: That might not be a good solution then, you might be able to take a copy of the `.csproj`/`.vbproj` file and in that version change the target framework to 3.5, and see if that works, of course you will have to change your references.

Comment: Ok, I might have to go down that road then. Made this thread because it did not feel like much fun and it is not ideal to inpose a constraint that prevents the use och .NET 4 for a bunch of projects due to this small add-in. I guess I was fishing for a somewhat magic solution.

Comment: Is there a way to keep everything targeting .NET 4.0 and just build it for 3.5?

Comment: I always thought those were the same thing.

Comment: Just my lack of skills speaking. Nothing is what it seems when it is making itself heard. I checked the code and it is not going to be an option to retarget to 3.5 by the way.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're stuck then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You could spawn a separate process and talk to it, but other than that, outta luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Inventor 2013 is compiled for .Net 4. That is not a patch I can easily apply at the moment.